# Issue with sorting algorithm - VB

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, sorting

I've been struggling with this algorithm below. It is supposed to loas the times inputted from eight textboxes into an array (txtTD1, etc). It then sorts them, and assigns each a numeric rank, which is displayed to the user (in txtR1, etc).

```
Dim timeArr(0 To 7) As String
timeArr(0) = txtTD1.Text
timeArr(1) = txtTD2.Text
timeArr(2) = txtTD3.Text
timeArr(3) = txtTD4.Text
timeArr(4) = txtTD5.Text
timeArr(5) = txtTD6.Text
timeArr(6) = txtTD7.Text
timeArr(7) = txtTD8.Text
System.Array.Sort(Of String)(timeArr)



Dim count As Integer = "1"
For i As Integer = 0 To 7
    If timeArr(i) = txtTD1.Text Then
        txtR1.Text = count
    ElseIf timeArr(i) = txtTD2.Text Then
        txtR2.Text = count
    ElseIf timeArr(i) = txtTD3.Text Then
        txtR3.Text = count
    ElseIf timeArr(i) = txtTD4.Text Then
        txtR4.Text = count
    ElseIf timeArr(i) = txtTD5.Text Then
        txtR5.Text = count
    ElseIf timeArr(i) = txtTD6.Text Then
        txtR6.Text = count
    ElseIf timeArr(i) = txtTD7.Text Then
        txtR7.Text = count
    ElseIf timeArr(i) = txtTD8.Text Then
        txtR8.Text = count
    End If
    count = count + 1
Next
```

It works perfectly, except when there are duplicates in the array. Say, for example, both txtTD1.text and txtTD2.text have been inputted to have the same value. In that case, the following occurs:

txtTD1   | txtR1

10:10.10 | 2

10:10.10 |

30:30.30 | 4

20:20.20 | 3

So, it skips first place, assigns second place to the first instance of the repeated value, and then skips the second instance.

I've used message boxes as a means of testing whether the sorting algorithm is working correctly, and each time it tells me that it is (i.e., 10:10.10 is first, and the second 10:10.10 is second - would prefer them to both be first and the next to be third, but not exactly sure how to do this).

So there is clearly an issue with the 'matching' algorithm. I'm certain it has to do with the use of IF statements, but I'm not sure what other control structure to use to avoid this issue.

I'd be appreciative for any insights and assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is this here:

```
    If timeArr(i) = txtTD1.Text Then
        txtR1.Text = count
    ElseIf timeArr(i) = txtTD2.Text Then
        txtR2.Text = count
    ElseIf timeArr(i) = txtTD3.Text Then
    ...
```

see: everytime you look at the text-boxes from `txtTD1` to `txtTD8` - so when two of them have the same value you will stop twice at the first of them (you are using `ElseIf` after all) and the second will be ignored no matter what.

The simplest thing I can think of is checking if a textbox is still empty on top of what you did:

```
Dim count As Integer = "1"
For i As Integer = 0 To 7
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtR1.Text) AndAlso timeArr(i) = txtTD1.Text Then
        txtR1.Text = count
...
```

of course for **each** of your textboxes.

---

#### Remarks

if you would put in some more thought you could easily stop this ugly copy&paste thing from happening ... but that is another question

Comment: Thanks, Carsten! Not the most efficient or elegant solution by any means, but your suggestion at least has it functioning properly. Thanks for your help!